# What is the point of JavaScript modules in browsers?

Tags: javascript, function, module

So I'm taking on coding project at the moment, and while I was digging around looking for a solution to tackle a particular problem, I came across 'modules'. While I've heard the term before, I decided that it would be worth looking into what modules actually were and how they were used.

From what I gathered, a module is a 'bit of code'. Be it, functions, variables, classes, that are present in one JavaScript file, that can be exported / imported, to / from another JavaScript file.

This seemed to be a bit pointless - why go to the trouble of exporting a script / set of scripts if I can use them from another file anyway?

Here's an example of what I'm on about:

```
// File 1 - adding.js

var c;

function add(a, b) {
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

```
// File 2 - main.js

var d;
d = add(6, 4);
```

As far as I know, that would work, `main.js` would be able to access scripts in `adding.js`, without needing to export the `add()` function.

Maybe its different when using non-browser JavaScript, or perhaps I've misunderstood what modules are, but if this is the case, why use modules at all?

Comment: Because managing everything as a global is *AN ENORMOUS PAIN IN THE BEHIND*. Try adding 5 libraries/files. Now make sure each is loaded after what it requires. Now update one. Oh, it has a new requirement - add that but at the correct place. Now realise that you will *not* have 5 libraries but likely 15-20. Try to leave a project for 6 months and come back to it - would you remember where each is used? Which one *is* used even?

Comment: Oh, and what happens when you add `File12` which also exposes a global `add` function but it works *slightly* differently? Perhaps it changes all arguments to positves. You may not even notice for months that `add(var1, var2)` doesn't work when `var2 = -10`.

Comment: If your entire program is a single function that adds two numbers then, ya, you probably don't need tools for managing code complexity.  Some programs tend to get more complex than that, though.

Comment: It's preferable not to pollute the global namespace. Your example does just that...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, so to clarify, its more of a "keep things clean & tidy" and make working with multiple files "efficient" as opposed to a necessity?

Comment: @MattSchofield: Depends on how one defines "a necessity".  There are those who like to keep everything global (not just in JavaScript) and rely on enough logic to make it work.  There are those who don't like modern IDEs and prefer the use of simple text editors, often claiming that the programmer should be able to make it work.  It's possible to program a web server with enough wires and a soldering iron, but it would be difficult to maintain.  Necessity is often an opinion, or driven by the specified needs of the system being built.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you are right, you don't need to `export` add function but you should be careful with the order of importing files.
Meaning that you should import `adding.js` before importing `main.js`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        ...
        <script src="adding.js">
        </script>
        <script src="main.js">
        </script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: That's not really an answer